# How to print on a new line in JSP

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jsp-tags

I had a database name which consists of two tables. I retrieved the data from both tables in the same JSP page.

I got the correct output, but I also got the both table data in only one line. I want to print a newline between each table.

I tried printing `\n` and `out.newline()`but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Print `<br />` instead of `\n`

Answer (score 1):

`\n` is a new line character in Java not in HTML.

If you want to have new line in HTML rendered by JSP, you could use `<BR>`. If you want to use it in scriptlet, use the following code:

```
<jsp:scriptlet>
   out.println("<BR>");
</jsp:scriptlet>
```